# How can I get the key from an array of objects based on a value?

Tags: jquery, arrays, color-palette

I have an array of color palettes as shown below. How can I get the key based on the value? For example, how can I get the key `Tomato` based on the value `#D50000`?

```js
var arrColorPalette = [{
  "Tomato": "#D50000"
}, {
  "Flamingo": "#E67C73"
}, {
  "Tangerine": "#F4511E"
}];
```

Comment: If you can change this structure, I would change it so that the property names in the objects are consistent, for instance: `{name: "Tomato", value: "#D50000"}`. Having inconsistent keys like that makes for more work.

Comment: Sadly, I can't change structure. :(